# setting up php session (session_set_save_handler)

Tags: php, mysql, function, session, session-set-save-handler

I am trying to set up a user login/logout system using php and mysql. I have found some documentation on the subject here: http://phpmaster.com/writing-custom-session-handlers/. I am trying to follow along with it (I have also been pulling from other sources too - but this is the main one).

Here is some of my code from "my_session_handler.php":

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {

    private $path = session_save_path();
    private $name = session_name();
    private $sessionId = session_id();

    function open($path, $name) {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=itit", "root", "bonjour3");

        $sql = "INSERT INTO session SET session_id =" . $db->quote($sessionId) . ", session_data = '' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session_lastaccesstime = NOW()";
        $db->query($sql);    


    ...
```

My question is, where are the "$path" and "$name" variables coming from in the example I cited above? I declared them as private variables and used some functions to do what I am thinking needs to be done. But on the website that I am following along with - neither of these variables get declared - along with $sessionId. I see that the read function returns $data. So I used it in the "write" function like this:

```
function write($sessionId, this.read($sessionId)) { 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=itit", "root", "bonjour3");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO session SET session_id =" . $db->quote($sessionId) . ", session_data =" . $db->quote($data) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session_data =" . $db->quote($data);
    $db->query($sql)
}
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters are used by the default session save handler, which saves the session data in files. They come from the `php.ini` file, and are used to form the filenames. They're supplied to your handler when PHP calls the `open()` method.

If you're writing a custom handler, you can ignore them, as the code on that web page does.

Comment: barmar...i have one more question - do i need to go about actually using the functions in the MySessionHandler? For example...do I need to use the close() function when I want to close a session? Or does the session handler do all that for me?

Comment: You don't use these functions directly, they're used by the session handler. When the application calls `session_close()`, the session handler calls your close function.